# Using boost message_queue otuside try/catch block

Tags: c++, boost

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FreeConsole();
    // Cannot construct mq here, it might fail
    // Declaring it here like `ipc::message_queue mq;`
    // throws some weird error given below
    try
    {
        ipc::message_queue mq(ipc::open_only, g_szPipeName);
        mq.send(g_szMsgReady, sizeof(g_szMsgReady) + 1, 0);
    }
    catch (const ipc::interprocess_exception &ex)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("This process is not meant to be used directly, yet ;)"), nullptr, MB_OK);
        exit(-1);
    }
    // How to use `mq` here?
    return 0;
}
```

Error thrown when I declare `message_queue`:

```
Error (active)  E0330
"boost::interprocess::message_queue_t<VoidPointer>::message_queue_t() [with VoidPointer=boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, ptrdiff_t, uintptr_t, 0Ui64>]" (declared at line 71 of "C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\\x64-windows\include\boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp") is inaccessible
```

I have installed the entire `boost` v1.77.0 library through `vcpkg`. Seems like a nested `try/catch` block is the only solution.

Comment: Is `g_szPipeName` already created i.e. is not null?

Comment: @kiner_shah its a `constexpr` I defined in a header, this file is `Main.cpp`, `g_szPipeName` is defined in `Main.h`

Answer (score 0):

Create the variable outside. If you use it after, it may also throw exceptions, so why would you want to ignore those?

Regardless, you can, of course, store it in some singleton container type (any smart-pointer or `optional`):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5e9aae6b92e4f0f)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;

static inline constexpr auto       g_szPipeName   = "Test";
static inline constexpr char const g_szMsgReady[6] = {"READY"};

int main()
{
    std::optional<ipc::message_queue> mq;
    try
    {
        mq.emplace(ipc::open_only, g_szPipeName);
        mq->send(g_szMsgReady, sizeof(g_szMsgReady), 0);
    } catch (const ipc::interprocess_exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 255;
    }

    mq->send(g_szMsgReady, sizeof(g_szMsgReady), 0);
}
```

> Note how if your `g_szMsgReady` is like mine, your `sizeof(...)+1` was out of bounds, leading to UB.

Prints, on my box: "No such file or directory" (obviously I don't have the named queue created)

Comment: "`sizeof(...)`+1 was out of bounds", I don't understand it. the **g_sz** part indicated that is a global `const char*`. Tbh I don't know what `string_view` is. C++ keeps adding new stuff. Anyways do you have an idea why declaring `mq` caused errors?

Comment: Oh oops. I had intended to remove the string view. It should have been `char const x[]` obviously. And the size of that array already includes the NUL character by definition

Comment: @demberto Same as any variable declaration: if it's not default-constructible you need to pass suitable constructor arguments.